# Delete white spaces after certain character

Tags: awk, sed, grep, perl

I'm using this `sed` command to delete the word `--More--` :

```
sed 's/--More--\s*/ /' tabladetallada.dat
```

the original file looks like this:

```
Device ID: BIOTERIO
  IP address: 148.228.83.189
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/6,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
 --More--         Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
  IP address: 148.228.4.192
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/23
Device ID: LAB_PESADO
  IP address: 148.228.131.130
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/11,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.131.130
Device ID: Arquitectura_Salones
  IP address: 148.228.135.61
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/9,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/49
  IP address: 148.228.135.61
Device ID: CIVIL_253
  IP address: 148.228.132.253
 --More--         Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/4,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0/52
  IP address: 148.228.132.253
Device ID: Arquitectura
  IP address: 148.228.134.253
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/3,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.134.253
Device ID: ING_CIVIL
  IP address: 148.228.133.251
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/7,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
  IP address: 148.228.133.251
Device ID: ING_CIVIL_DIR
  IP address: 148.228.4.188
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/10,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
Device ID: Ingenieria_Posgrado
  IP address: 148.228.137.253
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/8,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.137.253
Device ID: Biblio_Barragan
  IP address: 148.228.136.61
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.136.61
Device ID: Electronica_Edif_3
 --More--           IP address: 148.228.130.253
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/5,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.130.253
```

Once the word is deleted the white spaces after it are still there
How can I delete them?

```
Device ID: BIOTERIO
  IP address: 148.228.83.189
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/6,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
           Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
  IP address: 148.228.4.192
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/23
Device ID: LAB_PESADO
  IP address: 148.228.131.130
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/11,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.131.130
Device ID: Arquitectura_Salones
  IP address: 148.228.135.61
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/9,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/49
  IP address: 148.228.135.61
Device ID: CIVIL_253
  IP address: 148.228.132.253
           Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/4,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0/52
  IP address: 148.228.132.253
Device ID: Arquitectura
  IP address: 148.228.134.253
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/3,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.134.253
Device ID: ING_CIVIL
  IP address: 148.228.133.251
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/7,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
  IP address: 148.228.133.251
Device ID: ING_CIVIL_DIR
  IP address: 148.228.4.188
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/10,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
Device ID: Ingenieria_Posgrado
  IP address: 148.228.137.253
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/8,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.137.253
Device ID: Biblio_Barragan
  IP address: 148.228.136.61
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.136.61
Device ID: Electronica_Edif_3
             IP address: 148.228.130.253
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/5,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.130.253
```

Comment: Cesar why are you asking the same question twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution should look like

```
s/--More-- */ /
```

or

```
s/--More--[[:blank:]]*/ /
```

`sed` does not know about `\s` for "space" but treats it as a literal `s`.

`␣*` (space + `*`) will match zero or more spaces.

`[[:blank:]]*` will match zero or more spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` as follow:

```
sed 's/--More--[[:space:]]//g' file
```